# Reference request - Books on Israel-Palestine conflict

Tags: 20th-century, israel, palestine

I am searching for a good even-handed account of the Israel-Palestine conflict. I read James Gelvin's book which was ok but I found lacking in detail when it came to the situation in more recent times. What I would like to read is a readable yet detailed book that documents how each side approached the conflict. As an outsider you hear both sides claiming that at different stages the opposite party was not really in for peace or that they missed a chance by having unreasonable demands. I think the best way to approach such hot topics is to establish the facts all parties agree on and then slowly evaluate each sides's claims where they differ, that is what I want. A maximally factual account of the situation that stays clear of ramblings (I guess no Finkelstein or Blumenthal) and also highlights when equally reliable sources make different claims.

One book that caught my eye is Ian Black's "Enemies and Neighbours", your thoughts?

All the best!

Comment: Requests for references and opinions on books are normally closed as subjective. Please check discussion on meta.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Where else can I ask for a reference? Don't suggest reddit, that thing is a cesspool.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer that - I can only answer that our community standards discourage reference requests and other subjective questions.  I'd start with Wikipedia and then check the references cited there.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace  This is weird to me.  A difficult reference request wouldn't be closed on the mathematics stack exchange, for example.  (An easy one would be--no one wants the place cluttered with people asking for calculus textbook recommendations.  But I think everyone would be fine if someone asked for a good reference for second-order ZF, for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Dennis Ross' book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0374529809) for an account of the negotiations that led to the breakdown of the Oslo accords.

A good book about the Mandatory Period is Tom Segev's [One Palestine, Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805065873).

Read any book you find critically. Virtually anyone writing about this issue has an ax to grind.